# Print packet protocol type using PyShark

Tags: python, protocols, arp, pyshark, imp

I want to print all the protocols of the packet (ie: ICMP, ARP, TCP, UDP, etc.) but I am getting only TCP and UDP. I am using pyshark and python to capture packets.

```
import pyshark 

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='eth0')
capture.sniff(timeout=50)
for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    protocol = packet.transport_layer
    src_addr = packet.ip.src
    src_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].srcport
    dst_addr = packet.ip.dst
    dst_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].dstport

    print (localtime,"\t",protocol,"\t", src_addr,"\t", src_port,"\t", dst_addr, "\t", dst_port)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are only getting `TCP` and `UDP` packets is because you are calling the `transport_layer`.

Reference: [Pyshark Dynamic Layer References](https://thepacketgeek.com/pyshark/packet-object/)

Here is one way to see the layers of an individual packet:

```
import pyshark

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture('en0')
for packet in capture:
    protocol = packet.layers
    print(protocol)
    filtered...
    [<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>, <NBSS Layer>, <SMB2 Layer>]
    [<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>]
    [<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <UDP Layer>, <QUIC Layer>]
    [<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>, <HTTP Layer>]
    [<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <TCP Layer>, <TLS Layer>]
    [<ETH Layer>, <ARP Layer>]
    truncated...
```

You can access the `highest packet layer` this way:

```
import pyshark

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture('en0')
for packet in capture:
    layer = packet.highest_layer
    print(layer)
    filtered...
    ARP
    DNS
    TCP
    HTTP
    UDP
    truncated...
```

I'm not sure what your use case is for parsing all the data related to a packet.

Here is a [document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/pyshark_packet_analysis) that I wrote on parsing packet data with `pyshark`.

Here is some [documentation](https://thepacketgeek.com/pyshark/packet-object/) for `pyshark` that provides information on parsing packet data.

If you need any additional help, please let me know and I will help you.